# When switching tabs in Android, what does it constitute?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

I have three tabs and each one is its own activity.  When I switch tabs I want my Spinner to update but I don't know what method gets called on tab switch.  Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook up a listener to the TabHost.OnTabChangeListener. You main activity extends TabActivity and its onCreate method probably looks something like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabs1, tabHost.getTabContentView(), true);

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator("tab1")
            .setContent(R.id.view1));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3")
            .setIndicator("tab2")
            .setContent(R.id.view2));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3")
            .setIndicator("tab3")
            .setContent(R.id.view3));
}
```

To hook up the listener, add the following code in your onCreate() method:

```
    tabHostt.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        if(tabId.equals("tab1")) {
            //tab1
        }
        else if(tabId.equals("tab2")) {
            //tab2
        }
        else if(tabId.equals("tab3")) {
            //tab3
        }
    }
});
```

HTH

Comment: I really new at this, how would I go about that?
I have 4 files, one that runs on app launch and every other one is an activity for a tab.

Comment: I've updated my answer above to include code on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener()
    {
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
        {
            //Do stuff in here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok, so that now gets called when I switch my tabs!  Now I just need to tell it to run a method in the activity it's switching from.  Help?

Comment: Just add a call to the method where the "Do stuff" comment is.

Comment: I have another question.  This executes when any tab is changed.  But can I have a method inside my activity the executes when the tab that is that represents that activity is selected or de-selected.

Comment: Mitchell, dhaag23's answer below should help you with that.

Comment: I don't think I was clear and I apologize for wating your time with my lack of Android Knowledge, but I was wondering if I could have a method inside my tab's activity class that could detect when it was selected or de selected.  These both reside in the TabHost file so I run into static verse non static issues.

Comment: Perhaps making use of the onPause and onResume methods?

Comment: Nothing to apologize for at all. I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for though. The onTabChanged method will fire any time a tab is selected, and you can use the if(tabId.equals("")) method dhaag23 suggested to check which tab has been selected.